# Factors affecting leniency of an evaluator (judge)

Tags: test, io-psychology, human-factors

I am interested in psychology evidence on determinants of leniency of an evaluator. The evaluator will assess a service that is directly related to them (for example, customer satisfaction, or student's teaching evaluation).

There are some papers on Accounting and Business research (like [Moers, 2005](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0361368203000977)) suggesting determinants of biased subjective performance evaluations. But I would be more interested in psychological evidence.

Will older evaluators be more lenient? Will married evaluators be more lenient? I have some feelings that these may be true, but could not find any academic evidence.

Are there any other systematic differences in characteristics of the more lenient evaluators?